# How many activities per week should I be doing with my scrum team?

Tags: scrum, agile, scrum-master

As a scrum master, I don’t want to take my team away from their committed sprint work too much so here is my question:

If you had to take a relatively high performing team, how many workshops would you do with them in a typical week other than the usual ceremonies?

Comment: what kind of workshops are you talking about? Are they about the technical direction of the product, or about the functioning of the team, or something else?

Comment: Agile. Taking the team to the next level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said they are high performing, so there seems to be little need for immediate improvement outside the usual feedback cycle.

I'd say whenever you see the need for improvement in the retrospective, ask if the team should do a workshop on that topic in a subsequent sprint. That way the whole team (including the PO) can decide if it's necessary and in which sprint.

In a typical week, I'd do less than one. Assuming a two week sprint, one workshop on Scrum processes per sprint already seems a lot for a "high performing" team.

Answer (score 4):

How many activities should you organise?

None.

How many activities should you facilitate if requested by the team?

As many as they want.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Would this apply just to a high performing team or also to a team which is completely new to agile.

Comment: With a team new to agile I would be more likely to suggest activities, but it would always be up to the team if they wanted to do them. I might say something like: "If you like, I can arrange a design meeting for later in the week?". The key is to empower the team to make their own decisions and ensure you are their to support them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular number associated with this, but I think it should be totally based on outcomes of your daily Scrum meeting (daily standup) which is must.

In Scrum meeting if you find something which is blocking deliverables then to overcome those you may need to align more sessions/meeting.

Comment: How would a workshop about the Agile process help with blockers in their daily work?

Comment: My bad, I thought workshop is about the ceremonies and not about the agile process.  If its more about educating team on Agile process then I think it should be periodically as and when you spotted the improvements